# Why is creating a directory not working in my MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a web application and I allow my users to upload files in one of the forms.  I want my method to create a folder when the upload is initiated that has the name of the passed in parameter, in this case, ID.

```
public ActionResult Async_Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int? id)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        string filepath = "/Content/CarData/";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath + id);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(filepath + id), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }
    }
    return Content("");
}
```

When the user uploads a file, however, an error is thrown:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:\GitRepos\MyProject\MyProject\Content\CarData\206\mclaren.jpg'.'

This is accurate because I can see that the directory isn't created.  Can anyone assist me with understanding what has gone wrong? I get no errors on the `Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath + id);` part of the method.

Comment: By default the application pool does not have system level access in order to create directories. Basically it does not have enough permission to do so. Try creating a user for your application pool with elevated privileges.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `MapPath` on one occasion where you're trying to talk to the file system, and not use it in another occasion where you're talking to the file system?